# Is postfix 3.0.x available for ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: postfix

version 3 of postfix includes a very useful BCC function in header_checks.  Is there a tested build of version 3.0.x available for ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Comment: You can download it here http://linux.softpedia.com/dyn-postdownload.php/26c9d1fc055aecab694aaa175ee0e90e/56a9339e/a40/0/1?tsf=0

Answer (score 0):

No there is not in the repository atleast. There is version 2.11.0-1.

You can search for packages from here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/.